# How to use expression to add 2 columns in terraform for snowflake

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to see if I can do a derived/calculated column during snowflake table creation. I am using terraform for this. Below is the code. I am unable to find the correct syntax to do this.

Couple of things i have tried to do so far are ...

```
expression=["C1"]+["C2"]
expression=snowflake_table.table.C1+snowflake_table.table.C2
expression=snowflake_table.table.name.C1+snowflake_table.table.name.C2
```

Reference:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/0.72.0/docs/resources/table

```
resource "snowflake_table" "table" {
  database            = snowflake_database.db.name
  schema              = snowflake_schema.schema.name
  name                = "RAWTABLE"
    
    column {
      name     = "C1"
      type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
    }

    column {
      name     = "C2"
      type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
    }

    column {
      name     = "C3"
      type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
      default {
        expression = ["C1"]+["C2"]
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not much details in the documentation about the default expression
 https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/0.72.0/docs/resources/table#expression where did you get that syntax from?

Comment: the official examples do not have expressions:
https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/terraform-provider-snowflake/blob/main/examples/resources/snowflake_table/resource.tf
... not looking good

Comment: How would you do this outside Terraform?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda create table foo (id bigint, id2 bigint, derived bigint as (id + id2));

insert into foo (id,id2) values (1,2), (2,2), (3,1);

select * from foo;

Comment: I tested creating that table manually in Snowflake and then doing an import in terraform to see how that third column looks like, for terraform that columns does not exist! , just like it is not there... a terraform plan is happy just with the first two columns after the import ... I report this to the project: https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/terraform-provider-snowflake/issues/2418

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `snowflake` keep that in mind while you read this suggestion...

If I was tasked with something like what you are asking I would approach it in  a different way, instead of having that calculated column *(if that is even possible)* I would use a view instead, that allows for many more options, you have access to the full SQL query to build what you need.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/view

```txt
resource "snowflake_view" "view" {
  database = snowflake_database.db.name
  schema   = snowflake_schema.schema.name
  name     = "view"

  comment = "comment"

  statement  = <<-SQL
    select * from foo;
SQL
  or_replace = false
  is_secure  = false
}
```